# Ubuntu cyrillic filenames

Tags: ubuntu, filenames

I have nginx on Mac and production nginx on ubuntu 11.10. In the static web-site I have files with cyrillic letters in filename. On mac they are found by the system. On ubuntu nginx writes in log

```
2: No such file or directory.
```

Specifically not all russian filenames get unaccepted. Only those having 'й' character in the filename. Any ideas?

It is not a nginx issue. Because I get same `No such file` when I just try to `cat <filename>`. Any even cyrillic filename passes, but those with 'й'. Maybe some other characters also are broken, I just didn't stumbled upon them.

Character 'й' is a standard contemporary character, not any kind of cyrillic-extended or whatever pre-historical letter.

Answer (score -1):

Use russian characters in filename is wrong way in production server. Just rename all of files   before use.

Or try use  locale  as like this

- LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8
- LANGUAGE=ru_UA:ru
- LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_MESSAGES="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"
- LC_ALL=ru_UA.UTF-8